# Testing unity game into android device keeps stopping it (Unity3D)?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, debugging

My game runs fine when i run it in unity3d ,but when it try to run it in my phone it does not even start and show this msg "MyAppName keeps stopping"
how can i locate the problem , I am not experienced
Thanks

"MyAppName keeps stopping"

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run it as a *Development Build*?
If you check the Development Build check box in build settings, you can see error messages (console messages) in your game.

Comment: I build it with Development Build and run it in my device but still the same msg , where can i see the console messages ?

Comment: It should pop up on your screen. I can't check it for Android, but for PC it's a little red box inside of your game environment showing the console output. Try out to trigger it with *Debug.Log()*.
But since it's not showing up for you, I am afraid, that this solution may not be helpful to you.

Comment: it crashes as soon as i try to launch it

Comment: Try with logcat and will see the error, Its available from Android Studio and ADB